# How come I can print out each character separately but not as a whole?

Tags: c, server, cs50

This is one part of a server implementation where I'm going through the request line header and giving output accordingly. This might be a basic question. How come I can print out each character separately but not the string as whole?

Has this something to do with mismanagement of memory?

This is part of pset6 in [CS50](http://cs50.net/).

```
 #include <ctype.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>

 int
 main(int argc, char * argv[])
 {
    char* line = "GET /cat.html HTTP/1.1";

    char* method = strstr(line, "GET");
    if (strcmp(method, line) != 0)
    {
        printf("405 Method Not Allowed");
    }

    printf("%s\n", line);

    char* requestTarget = malloc(10);
    char* ch = strchr(line,'/');
    if (ch != NULL)
    {
        int i = 0;
        for (i = (ch-line); i < strlen(line)-9; i++)
        {
            requestTarget[i] = line[i];
            printf("%c", requestTarget[i]);
        }
        requestTarget[i] = '\0';
    }

    else
         printf(" 501 Not Implemented");

    printf("requestTarget: %s\n", requestTarget);

    free(requestTarget);
    return 0;
 }
```

A side note, I know it's bad pratice to hard code in `-9` in my for lop `strlen(line)-9`. But I couldn't figure out how to just read the characters in the requested target `cat.html`. And I know that the header is specified by `method SP request-target SP HTTP-version CRLF`(is CRLF aka `\r\n` two characters?) So `-9` works (I think) but maybe not the best.

EDIT: I edited my loop so that I add an null terminator at the end. This was originally meant to be in, but since I have edited my code so much now it was mistakenly taken out. It still does not work though.

Comment: You want to learn what C-"strings" actually are, that they are just a `char`-array terminated by a `'\0'` (aka `null`, aka `NUL` (*one* ell only), aka `0`).

Comment: You are supposed to solve this ony your own. And you should definitively have learned how to already - unless you skipped vital lessons. (And make `line` `const`!)

Comment: @Olaf Accoring to the Academig Honesty, under Resonable `Sharing snippets of your own code online so that others might help you identify and fix a bug.` Further more, this is just a simple test program, I have only declared ´variable´ so that I can test my diffrent functions. The original `line` is part of the distrobution code.

Comment: @FelixRosén: I did not say you shall not ask if you encounter a problem in general. But qhat you are asking about is basic stuff you should have learned already. If not, you either missed lessons, or have general lack of understanding these basics. I don't want to offend you. Just make your own conclusions and actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has undefined behavior, because it writes past the space that you allocated.

You do this copy

```
requestTarget[i] = line[i];
```

when `i` points to some location in the middle of the `line[]`, but `requestTarget` requires a smaller index. You need to "translate" the index, or create a separate one for the destination:

```
int j = 0;
for (int i = (ch-line); i < strlen(line)-9; i++, j++)
{
    requestTarget[j] = line[i];
    printf("%c", requestTarget[j]);
}
requestTarget[j] = '\0';
```

**Note:** you need to make sure that `requestTarget` has enough space for the characters that you wish to store in it, including the null terminator.

Comment: I had it like that before, but didnt work. It was ment to be in this post aswell, but i have edited my code so many times now so it was mistakenly taken out.

Comment: @FelixRosén Take a look at the edit. It should fix the problem with indexing.

Comment: Yes, Thank you, it worked when i did `requestTarget[j] = line[i]` which i think you were ment to say. Thank you!